# Why matplotlib plot a graph have ticks line off-axis ？

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I use matplotlib plot graph on OS X system,the top left corner ticks line have off-axis distribution，but,on windows,there is no this problem.how to deal with this problem？

[image]

Comment: Note that the y-tick at 0.10 is slightly too far to the right as well.

Comment: I don't set the y-tick, just plot.show() ,and I find all matplotlib running on OSX system will hava these problem.

Answer (score 0):

I Have work out this problem,

1.savefig() do not support the jpg,tif ,so if save the graph use this format, the graph tick line will off-axis.if save the graph use png,eps,svg,the graph will have no this problem

2.show graph program have a bug on OS X system, no matter which format of graph you save,it will always show tick line off-axis.